# How can I make a SeekBar in android go from 100 to 0 instead of the default?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a seekBar in android studio which is working, but I would like to make it go from 100 to 0 instead of 0 to 100. How can I do this ? I've been trying to set min and max but that won't change anything. Thank you :D

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to update a second variable with 100 - the current `SeekBar` value when it changes e.g.

```
private int opposite;

public void onValueChanged(int value)
{
   opposite = 100 - value;
}
```

I haven't got the docs to hand so the method name is probably wrong, but that should sort it out

Comment: Thank you. That is so simple and so smart in the same time. It worked :D